# A way to infer json data scheme in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say that i have dataframe with column `data`.
In this column i have a string with json inside.
The trick is that that json is not always full, some attributes may be missing in some rows.

See sample below for a clarity

```
column_name_placeholder | data
foo                      {"attr1":1}
foo                      {"attr2":2}
bar                      {"attr0":"str"}
bar                      {"attr3":"po"}
```

What i'm looking for is a way to infer full json schema for an each key in "column_name_placeholder"

so the answer would be something like this

```
foo
{
"attr1":int,
"attr2":int
}
bar
{
"attr0":string,
"attr3":string
}
```

Only way i imaging i can do that is to go down to RDD level and infer schema with some kind of 3rd party library on map stage and merge that schema again with some 3rd party library on reduce stage

Am i missing some spark *magic?

Answer (score 2):

You can transform into RDD and read again using `spark.read.json` and let it infer the schema.

Example for `column_name_placeholder = bar`:

```
spark.read.json(
    df.filter("column_name_placeholder = 'bar'").rdd.map(lambda row: row.data)
).printSchema()

#root
# |-- attr0: string (nullable = true)
# |-- attr3: string (nullable = true)
```